# Unable to capture the delete keypress in a jQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-lists, keypress

I really need your help,

I am trying to capture the delete keypress in the UL #refdocs_list but for some strange reason, when I hit the delete key, nothing happens and I get no message.

I am at a loss for solutions.

Here is the markup in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>

<style type="text/css">
.refdoc_selected {
    background-color: rgb(10,36,106);
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showDialog() {

var refdocs = [12256363,96415678,96857456,12236748]

            var markup ='<div style="margin-bottom: 2px;">' +
                            '<p style="margin: 0; padding:0;">' +
                                '<input style="margin-top: 1px; margin-right: 2px" float: left;" id="refdocs_input" type="text" class="field_outline inputbox">'+    
                                '<button id="btn_add_refdoc" class="button" style="margin-right: 2px;"><img style="width: 14px;" src="images/icon_check.png"></button>'+
                                '<button id="btn_del_refdoc" class="button" style="margin-right: 2px;"><img src="images/icon_delete.png"></button>'+
                                '<button id="btn_empty_refdocs" class="button" style="margin-right: 2px;"><img src="images/icon_trash.png"></button>'+
                            '</p>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="field_outline" style="background: #FFF; min-height: 75px; max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">'+
                        '<ul id="refdocs_list" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;"></ul>'+
                        '</div>'

            $("<div></div>").dialog({
                modal: false,
                title: "Reference Documents",
                width: 350,


                open: function () {

                    $(this).html(markup)

                    for (var i = 0; i < refdocs.length; i++){   
                        $("#refdocs_list").append('<li style="background-image: url(images/icon_doc.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 50%; padding: 4px 0 2px 16px;">'+ refdocs[i] +'</li>')
                    }


                     $("#refdocs_list li").click(function() {
                       $(this).addClass("refdoc_selected").siblings().removeClass("refdoc_selected")
                        document.getElementById('refdocs_input').value = $(this).text()
                     });

                    //NOT WORKING:
                    $('#refdocs_list ul').keyup(function(e){
                        if(e.keyCode == 46) {
                            alert('Delete Key Pressed');
                        }
                    });


                },
                close: function(){
                     $(this).remove();
               },
               buttons: [
                {
                    text: "CLOSE",
                    "class": 'button',
                    click: function() {

                        $(this).dialog("close")
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "CANCEL",
                    "class": 'button',
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close")
                    }
                }
            ]


            });//end dialog 
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="button" onclick="showDialog()" value="test">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach it to the body:

```
$('body').keyup(function (e) {    
    if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        alert('Delete Key Pressed');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach the Keyup event to the dialog itself by:

```
$(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
 if (e.which == 46) { do whatever }
});
```